# Changing ActionBar Height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I changed the ActionBar height in themes.xml with this

```
<item name="actionBarSize">30dp</item>
```

The height of ActionBar changes but then it throws the alignment of my first control off.

Before changing ActionBar height:

[image]

After changing Actionbar height

[image]

The first Spinner control is aligned to the top of the Layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">



<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spSessionsMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
```

I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the Action bar has a min height of 64dp by default defined in its style :

ActionBar style : (Just for reference don't copy paste this in your theme)

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
  <item name="titleTextStyle">?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6</item>
  <item name="subtitleTextStyle">?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1</item>
  <!-- Overrides minimum height in landscape to avoid headline6 and subtitle1 height concerns. -->
  <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/mtrl_toolbar_default_height</item>
  <item name="maxButtonHeight">@dimen/mtrl_toolbar_default_height</item>
</style>
```

If you want to remove the gap between your spinner and the action bar you can override the min height of the bar. like this :

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
   <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
</style>
```

Then add this line to your main theme :

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
```

Comment: Not working. I'm using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar

'<style name="Theme.Inventory" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">' 

After implementng what you suggested, I get a blank white area for the ActionBar

Comment: I figured it out. I changed my main theme to Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge
Then used <item name="actionBarSize">35dp</item>   No more gap

Comment: @Beachdog it should also work on DayNight.DarkActionBar theme as it inherits actionBarStyle from Light.ActionBar theme. i tried it and it is still working. you don't need to use bridge unless u are doing something else .

Comment: @Beachdog can u tell me what exactly u did ? what code u pasted in your themes.xml and what not ?

Comment: created a new style
 <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item> </style>
Then themes.xml I referenced the new style 
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>

That resulted in the ActionBar being just white space

Comment: bro u mis typed the parent in CustomActionBar style, watch again its "Widget.MaterialComponents.Light.ActionBar.Solid" not "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"

Comment: @Beachdog fix this and try again, it'll will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240381/discussion-between-beachdog-and-drhowdydoo).